# Old json data is fetched even after json file is modified

Tags: android, json, android-ion

I am using [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) (Android Asynchronous Networking and Image Loading) to fetch json data stored in gist.github.com.
Whenever I add new data to the `JSON` file in github and restart the `android` app, the new data is not loaded but when I clear the cache of the app and restart the app, new data is loaded. I am unable to solve the caching problem here. I think the networking library is caching the `JSON` file. Please help.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("https://gist.github.com/<username>/<gistId>/raw/data.json")
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
    // Do something
 }
});
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

use .noCache() to bypass caches.

Comment: I tried but it is giving the same result. noCache() works with bitmap but I don't know why it's not working here. Thanks